# Key input not registered when kept pressed

Tags: windows-7, laptop, keyboard

A few days ago I've been having a bit of an issue with some of the keys on my keyboard of my laptop. Been looking on google and trying out some stuff which I thought could help, but I didn't find anything that helped or I simply don't know the correct search terms. Anyhoo, here's the problem:

When I press down the 'z' key and keep it pressed in e.g. notepad, it starts typing a series of z's, however after a random time (could be after 3 z's or after 200 z's), I see the input is stuttering and the z's are no longer being typed and then after another random time, it starts typing again. Not all keys are fault however, it only seems to occur on Z and S. Just to clarify, I don't believe this is a screen-freeze issue of some sort, there's no delay, the input is just not captured.

At first I thought I was just kidding myself that this happened, but then I used this [tool](http://hot-virtual-keyboard.com/) to monitor the key presses on the screen. I noticed that, even though I kept the key pressed, the tool showed that the key was released. After a short time it showed it was pressed again, sometimes it showed it was stuttering. I think you get the picture.

When typing normally, I don't have any of these issues at all. My keys correspond just fine in this case and every letter gets typed out perfectly.

First thing that came to mind were keyloggers interfering, but my anti-virus didn't show anything. Then I thought maybe it's something with my drivers. So reinstalled the drivers, nothing happened. Then I checked if there was any dirt underneath the keys and decided to just take the cap off and clean the whole thing, but to no avail. Finally I just formatted my entire PC and reinstalled the whole thing from scratch, but the problem is still persistent. The only thing I didn't do, is upgrading my BIOS version.

So now, I'm starting to think there's something wrong, I just don't know what it could be or how I can fix it. I'm hoping some of you would have an idea or ran into something similar. I'm sorry if this has already been asked before, but I didn't find a question which stated the exact same problem. Thanks in advance!

---

Update: over the past few weeks, the keys don't even work for typing anymore, unless my laptop is consuming a lot of CPU/RAM memory. For some reason the keys then automatically start working again.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess answer to your problem is that it is actually a hardware defect.

Though this is something of an oversimplification, keyboards use a controller to interpret your key presses, and convert them to computer-understandable commands.  Generally, keyboards use a matrix to determine which key is pressed (i.e. key 5th column, 5th row is "F").  The keys which you are having a problem with might be on positions in the matrix that aren't prioritized correctly in the controller, so the controller is overloaded, and isn't properly showing the keypresses.

Again, a guess.  But it's obviously a hardware problem, not a software one based on the steps you've taken.

Comment: I just got a USB keyboard and tested it with that one as well. Everything is just fine with the USB one. I'm not sure if this matters, but I'm guessing my laptop's keyboard is having hardware issues then?